# Body text disappearing in random posts

Tags: posts

I'm using Wordpress 3.5.1

I noticed recently on my site that the body content of some posts is disappearing. The post still exists, all the other fields are still populated, but the post_content field is empty. It seems pretty random -- different post types; sometimes it happens immediately after content is created or updated, other times after it's just been sitting there untouched for weeks or months; some with complicated content, others with plain, short text entries.

I checked the database, and the post_content fields for these posts were empty. Often times, there was a separate autosave record that contained the post body, luckily. I've been using those to re-add the missing content.

Any ideas what could be causing the problem?

Comment: Your issue seems frustrating, but it is impossible for us to trouble shoot without something more concrete to go on. Is your host slow or unreliable possibly?

Comment: is the field "post_modified" contining the date of the changes/tuncation of the post, or did the "post_content" field change witout changing the "post_modified"

Comment: GhostToast, thank you, it is very frustrating. The host has been totally reliable so far.

Comment: Puggan Se, the post_modified field has changed.

Answer (score 0):

First you should update your WordPress to 3.6.  And then after that, make sure that the post is actually "published", and visible to the public.  If a post get's set to "private" it won't display unless a user with permission to alter the post is logged in.  It's a hard problem to diagnose without seeing your markup, or being able to log in personally.

Are you using a custom theme?

Comment: Thanks, I plan on updating to 3.6 soon. The posts are set to public. I don't think the problem is markup related, because the post content is disappearing from the database.

I am using a custom theme.